# hadoop cp vs streaming with /bin/cat as mapper and reducer

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop, have very basic question on hadoop copy (cp) vs hadoop streaming if /bin/cat is used for mapper and reducer.

hadoop  -input  -output 
-mapper /bin/cat -reducer /bin/cat

I believe above command would copy the files (how is it different from hadoop cp?) or correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

They kind of do the same thing but in different fashion:

- `hadoop cp` will just invoke the JAVA HDFS API and performs a copy to another specified location, which is way faster than streaming solution.
- `hadoop streaming` on the other (see the example command below) will kick off a mapreduce job. Hence like any other mapreduce job it has to go through `map -> sort & shuffle -> reduce` phases which will take a long time to complete depending on your input dataset size. Because of the default *sort & shuffle* phase your input data also gets sorted in the output directory.

  ```
  hadoop jar /path/to/hadoop-streaming.jar \
  -input /input/path
  -output /output/path
  -mapper /bin/cat
  -reducer /bin/cat
  ```